# HTML div with jquery on.click not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

Good day i have an html div written below.

```css
.SubmitOrder {
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  float: right;
  background: #C40514;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<div class="SubmitOrder">
  <?php echo "Total: ".$totalPrice."<br> Pay Now!" ?>

  <script>
    $('.SubmitOrder').on('click', function() {
      window.location.replace(<?php echo "home.php?account_id=$accountid" ?>);
    })
  </script>
</div>
```

But upon clicking the div it does not redirect me to the link. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: move the script outside the div

Comment: Add the html that that appears in your browser, copy it from the element inspector...

Comment: You are placing your javascript in an HTML element which will not work. Here is a link as for where you can utilize your javascript code: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be better to place your script inside the `head` part using the `ready` function will assure that all the targeted elements inside your script are loaded.

**NOTE :** You must also wrap the new link `<?php echo "home.php?account_id=$accountid" ?>` in single quotes `''`.

```
window.location.replace('<?php echo "home.php?account_id=$accountid" ?>');
```

```css
.SubmitOrder {
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  float: right;
  background: #C40514;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('.SubmitOrder').on('click', function() {
        window.location.replace('<?php echo "home.php?account_id=$accountid" ?>');
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="SubmitOrder">
    Total: 1000$
    <br> Pay Now!
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just wrapping the link made it work ! transferring the script to the header made it not work :)

Answer (score 0):

try this for javascript

```
<div class="SubmitOrder">
  <?php echo "Total: ".$totalPrice."<br> Pay Now!" ?>


</div>

  <script>
    $('.SubmitOrder').on('click', function() {
      window.location.replace(<?php echo "home.php?account_id=$accountid" ?>);
    })
  </script>
```

move script tag out of div with class `SubmitOrder`